# Intel UHD 630 works significantly better than NVIDIA RTX-2060(Mobile) on Ubuntu 19.10 & GNOME

Tags: nvidia, gnome, graphics, 19.10

I am very new to Ubuntu. I have a dual boot system. After some time starting to use Ubuntu, I found myself never running Windows 10 on my system unless I want to play Path of Exile. Since I generally spend 90% of my "sitting on the computer" time on Ubuntu, I want to solve the problem I've been facing.

If the system is running on the NVIDIA card, every type of animations on the graphical interface (GNOME) stutters. Not in any game though, especially DotA 2 works just fine. I'd like to add that it's also not like the lagging that I've experienced in 18.04 which was huge. In this case there is no lag, but the animations don't feel continuous, but they feel observably discrete if one pays attention. ***I also experience the very same thing when I scroll up and down while using firefox, and it drives me crazy.***

The weird thing is that this never happens if I *prime-select intel*. I firstly thought this could be a driver issue, so I've tried all options in *Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers*, which are *nvidia-430*, *nvidia-435* and *nouveau* drivers. Nothing ever changed. I also have downloaded the latest version provided for RTX-2060M by *nvidia.com* which was nvidia-440.xx, but Ubuntu never booted afterwards so I reinstalled the OS.

Is this a GNOME specific problem? Should I try another desktop environment? Because I have no experience doing it and I have privacy anxiety. If that's the case, which environment provides the best performance while ensuring privacy protection, preferably could also mimic the default GNOME themes with orangey & purpley patterns, because I love it so much.

Thanks in advance,
Name

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and if SSD, SSD firmware? Do not download directly from nVidia with .run file. You have to in effect re-install with every kernel update. Only use Ubuntu repositories. You may need the ppa to get latest driver. And absolutely must purge old driver before installing a new one. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2362351&p=13649946#post13649946 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Answer (score 0):

Known Gnome bug on hybrid graphics hardware (with workaround): https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/1202#note_524388